# RoboGuice: method needs a new instance each call, injection possible?

Tags: android, tdd, guice, roboguice

If I want to make a new instance of an injected class each time, how do I do it?  Here is the example that I am trying to do:

```
class Jet
{
  List<Missile> mAllMissiles;

  // 
  // make a new missile, and add it to the table.
  //
  void fireMissile()
  {
     Missile missile = new Missile();
     missile.doSomething();
     mAllMissiles.add(missile);
  }
}
```

Now, I can Inject the Missile, but wont it be the same missile each time?  Is this a case where I need to inject the Provider?

http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders

Or is there a different means of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, inject a `Provider<Missile>`. If you can inject `X`, you can inject `Provider<X>`, and vice-versa. Injecting a Provider is the best way of requesting multiple instances of a class from the injector.